# Orbiting bolo technology viability?

Tags: technology, transport, orbital

I have recently read Seveneves and loved the use of certain technologies in it. Has anyone put serious study into the bolo hanglider hanger and possible viable usage of a similar technology?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe what these things are for those who haven't read the books.

Comment: This is called a momentum exchange tether. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_exchange_tether

Comment: Earth launch assist bolo/space bolo. Earth-to-orbit rotovator cant be built from current materials re: thickness/mass to handle the loads too large but w/ 2/3rd rotation speed halves the centripetal acceleration stresses. Lower stress if pick up moving vehicle and sling it into orbit w/o rockets, or catch & lower it into atmospheric flight. Its easier for rockets to achieve speed, like Hypersonic Airplane Space Tether Orbital Launch (HASTOL). Air breathing or rocket to tether could save tons of fuel per flight, & allow simple vehicle w/ more cargo. Tethers Unlimited Inc working on it I hope

Comment: Why is it called a 'bolo'? Does that stand for anything? Is it a portmanteau word like rotovator which is from rotor and elevator?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Boeing did the [HASTOL study](http://www.niac.usra.edu/files/studies/final_report/391Grant.pdf) and it seems viable with current technology and economy, there is even [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyhook_(structure)) about it.

Besides of lifting cargo from hypersonic aircraft to orbit, the bolo can also generate power by [electrodynamic tethering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodynamic_tether) and there were even [several missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_tether_missions) testing it.

Comment: None of those shuttle missions listed in the Wikipedia article tested a "bolo".

Comment: @OrganicMarble not directly, but most of these tests are needed to build a reliable bolo: the micrometeorites and charge affects the tether, [the tether causes drag and lost of height](https://www.tethers.com/taking-out-the-space-trash-tethers-unlimited-announces-successful-operation-of-space-debris-removal-device/), it can get tangled in microgravity and more.

Comment: Why is it called a 'bolo'? Does that stand for anything? Is it a portmanteau word like rotovator which is from rotor and elevator?

Comment: @sandman I believe it stems from [bolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolas).